# Settings Action constant for Tethering settings page in Android 2.2 (Froyo)

Tags: settings, android-2.2-froyo, android-wifi

I am able to open Wifi settings screen using

startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));

I want to open the tethering and hotspot settings page using the same.Can anyone tell me the settings value i have to use instead of ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS.

Thanks 
Dheepak